# normalize columns into rows from pipe-delimited text stream

Tags: sql, perl, bash, awk, sed

I am looking for a concise, command line tool/script to take the output of another command and transform the text into a normalized data set for import to a database.

My input stream currently looks like this:

```
timestamp|identifier|column1|column2|...|column n
```

(representing n observations at the same time, for the same identifier (person) )

I want to grab the first two fields and then prepend them to column1-n to produce output like this:

```
timestamp|identifier|column1
timestamp|identifier|column2
timestamp|identifier|column3
...
timestamp|identifier|column n
```

sed? awk? perl? or, would it be better to load this data into a database table as-is, then use some kind of transform script stored procedure? I believe I've done this before in SQL Server using PIVOT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2, $i}' file
timestamp|identifier|column1
timestamp|identifier|column2
timestamp|identifier|...
timestamp|identifier|column n
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` set input and output field separator as `|`.
- `for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2, $i` loop through all fields since 3rd printing 1st col, 2nd col + current field.

Comment: awesome! I am amazed at how fast people who know this stuff have the answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", @F[0,1],$_ for @F[2..$#F]' file
```

output

```
timestamp|identifier|column1
timestamp|identifier|column2
timestamp|identifier|column n
```

Explanation:

`-F'\|'` is delimiter for implicit split, and it should it be escaped since it is regex

`-l` auto chomp newline, and adds one when printing

`-a` auto split into `@F` array

`-n` adds implicit `while(<>)` loop

or letting perl speak for itself,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", @F[0,1],$_ for @F[2..$#F]'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    our(@F) = split(/\|/, $_, 0);
    print join('|', @F[0, 1], $_) foreach (@F[2 .. $#F]);
}
```

Comment: @EdMorton perhaps asking someone familiar with lisp/scala/haskel? But if it makes any easier here is equivalent `for (@F[2..$#F]) { print join "|", @F[0,1],$_ }`

Comment: nicely done!! I find this particular syntax a more natural language form ... that is, print the first two fields of my array and join starting from third field to end of the line each separated with a `|`.

Comment: @jaypal well, now I feel good about myself.... Thanks for brightening up my day :-( !

Comment: `perl -aF\\\| -nle '$"="|"; print "@F[0,1,$_]" for 2..$#F' file`

Comment: `perl -F'\|' -lane '$,="|"; print @F[0,1,$_] for 2..$#F' file` but it might be misleading as `$,="|"` should be outside of the loop.